# Why isn't [1..5] == [1,2,3,4,5]?

Tags: ruby, arrays, comparison, compare, range

Why isn't `[1..5] == [1,2,3,4,5]`?

Why isn't `[1..5].to_a == [1,2,3,4,5]`?

How to convert from `[1..5]` to `[1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: `[1..5]` is the same as `[(1..5)]` (an Array containing one Range object). The `inspect` isn't very helpful if this isn't understood, but try `[1..5][0]` on the REPL which should clear things up.

Comment: Expand the range with `[*1..5]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`[1..5]` is an array which only has one element, the range object `1..5`

`[1..5].to_a` is still `[1..5]`

`(1..5).to_a` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 2):

`[1..5]` is an array with one element -  a range object, all attempts to iterate through it will fail.  array can have many kinds of objects in them.  In my example above I treat the range as just a range and make any array from it directly.

```
1.9.3-p125 :008 > (1..5).to_a  # Note regular parens.
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
1.9.3-p125 :009 >
```

To do more *closely* what you stated - starting with [1..5] - you could do:

```
1.9.3-p125 :013 > newarray = []

1.9.3-p125 :014 > [1..5][0].each {|e| newarray << e}
 => 1..5 
1.9.3-p125 :015 > newarray
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
1.9.3-p125 :016 >
```